# Can PHP run using file extensions other than ".php"?

Tags: php

I performed the following test:

1. I created a file called index.php, and within it, I'm doing an include of another file called mensagem.php
2. In this file mensagem.php, I show a message on the screen with the echo command.

Hence I decided to do a little test:

I changed the extension of this file to mensagem.php mensagem.stack, and to my surprise it was done and include php file was executed normally, and I have three questions:

1. Why did this happen?
2. If the htaccess i changed the index to message.txt what would happen?
3. For the server, usually when displaying a list of files on the server (Famous index of), because when we send save these files on PC, it does not come with source code, since PHP can be compared with one .doc / .txt. anything else?

Comment: The ".php" suffix of the index.php file indicates that the PHP interpreter should be called by the web server. However, once this is running, it no longer needs the server to invoke it - and PHP will do the include on any file, regardless of its name.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Why did this happen?** 
because it was made within an include file being parsed by php .. 
The file extension is irrelevant ... is a mere visual identification. What matters is the content of the file.

**2. Htaccess in case I change the index to message.txt what would happen?** 
would be displayed in the browser the literal content. txt file unless the. txt to be registered to be parsed by the compiler php

**3. In the case of the server, usually when displaying a list of existent files ...** 
because the server (apache, for example) is configured to parse files with nomenclarura. php within php compiler, so that the output result is obtained from the parsed script ..